# opencv image rescale wrong offsets

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have the following OpenCV2 code:

```
cv::Mat old = imread("some.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::resize(old, old, cv::Size(342,228));
//cv::resize(old, old, cv::Size(342*2,228*2));
```

Which when displayed in a QT container using

```
QImage qimg((uchar*)old.data, old.cols, old.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);
ui->ImgA->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));
```

gives me this result (ignore the unrelated slight green tint, that was my screenshot tool being slow...):

[image: Result of resizing using uncommented out opencv cv::resize]

When I switch to the commented out resize (aka 4x the size), I get a beautiful sunset photo with proper colors. It also works fine if I switch width and height.  Is there something I'm missing in my code that's causing this to have the wrong offset at certain resized sizes? (note the original JPG is 5472 pixels by 3648 pixels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
QImage qimg((uchar*)old.data, old.cols, old.rows,old.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

I posted it as a comment, but now I test it on my computer and without step I get same wrong picture, so I'm sure that it is solution of your problem.